# Evaluate $(1+i\sqrt{3})^8$ + $(1-i\sqrt{3})^8$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Evaluate $(1+i\sqrt{3})^8$ + $(1-i\sqrt{3})^8$.

Comment: You tagged this as [tag:geometry]. Does that mean that algebric manipulation using the binomial theorem or similar is out of the question?

Comment: Do you have any ideas? For example, what to do with $\;z^8+\overline z^8\;$ ? And I think some "complex numbers" tagging is missing

Comment: I'm pretty sure binomial theorem is out of the question here I am afraid!

Comment: I understand that it would be that DonAntonio but i'm not sure where to go from there?

Comment: Why is binomial th. Out of the question? $(a\pm b)^8 = a^8\pm 8a^7b+ 28a^6b^2\pm 56a^5b^3+70a^4b^4\pm 56a^3b^5 + 28a^2b^6 \pm 8ab^7+b^8$.  But if you *know* polar you *should* do polar.  Theses are exactly the types of problems polar is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With polar form we have,

$$1\pm i\sqrt{3}=2(\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})=2e^{\pm i \frac{\pi}{3}}$$

thus

$$(1\pm i\sqrt{3})^8=2^8e^{\pm i \frac{2\pi}{3}}$$

and

$$(1+i\sqrt{3})^8+(1-i\sqrt{3})^8=$$

$$2^9\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})=-2^8.$$

Comment: I understand how you get to the answer but where does the original statement come from?

Comment: Oh I see now! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$(1+\sqrt{3}i)^3=(1-\sqrt{3}i)^3=-8$$
$$(1+\sqrt{3}i)^2+(1-\sqrt{3}i)^2=-4$$

Comment: Would it be -1024?

Comment: no, it would be -256

Answer (score 0):

An idea with as little complex analysis as possible (to me):

$$a^8+b^8=(a^4+b^4)^2-2a^4b^4\implies z^8+\overline z^8=(z^4+\overline z^4)^2-2|z|^8$$

and now

$$(1\pm i\sqrt3)^2=-2\pm2i\sqrt3=2(-1\pm i\sqrt3)\implies (1\pm i\sqrt3)^4=4(-2\mp 2i\sqrt3)\implies $$

$$(4(-2-2i\sqrt3)+4(-2+2i\sqrt3))^2-2\cdot2^8=$$

$$=256-512=-256$$